# can delete column from database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, database

[image]

[image]

I write this query `ALTER TABLE com_product DROP COLUMN drug_id;` 
and 
then write this query but also error

```
ALTER TABLE com_product DROP FOREIGN KEY drug_id;
```

but error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please remove your foreign key reference on column drug_id.

```
ALTER TABLE com_product DROP FOREIGN KEY `com_product_ibfk_2`;
```

Then remove the column.

```
ALTER TABLE com_product DROP COLUMN drug_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete this column because it is the key of another table. There is a link between this 2 tables. You must take off this constraint first or empty your table.

Comment: but this not a primary key

Comment: @MuhammadTufail it does not matter, there is a foreign key constraint in your table. It means that _your column references another column on another table_. This constraint must be dropped before deleting the column.